# read TCP_CLIENT: Connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT) (code=10060)

Tags: openvpn

I have a user who is unable to connect to my OpenVPN server from outside of the country. My server is placed in Portugal and my client is triying Myanmar. The connection is always restarting, from user side. He is now using an old backup VPN through PPTP.

This server is working fine with users with Windows 10, Linux and MacOS, some of them, using the connection 8 hours per day, and is working fine still no problem detected after months of usage.

I am using a non standard connection through port TCP 51184 to avoid service blockage from ISPs to default ports and traffic shapping.

From user side logs, all sees good except this part:

```
Fri Jul 28 09:35:32 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]x:51194 [nonblock]
Fri Jul 28 09:35:33 2017 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]x:51194
Fri Jul 28 09:35:33 2017 TCP_CLIENT link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:0
Fri Jul 28 09:35:33 2017 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]x:51194
Fri Jul 28 09:36:14 2017 read TCP_CLIENT: Connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT) (code=10060)
Fri Jul 28 09:36:14 2017 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Fri Jul 28 09:36:14 2017 Unblocking outside dns using service succeeded.
Fri Jul 28 09:36:14 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
```

From server side logs is this what is happening in general:

```
Jul 28 04:13:23 openvpn 90566   rui.m/103.x.205.111:63802 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, client-instance restarting
Jul 28 04:13:23 openvpn 90566   rui.m/103.x.205.111:63802 [rui.m] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Jul 28 04:13:18 openvpn 90566   MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
Jul 28 04:13:18 openvpn 90566   MANAGEMENT: CMD 'quit'
Jul 28 04:13:18 openvpn 90566   MANAGEMENT: CMD 'status 2'
Jul 28 04:13:18 openvpn 90566   MANAGEMENT: Client connected from /var/etc/openvpn/server1.sock
Jul 28 04:12:16 openvpn 90566   MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
Jul 28 04:12:16 openvpn 90566   MANAGEMENT: CMD 'quit'
Jul 28 04:12:16 openvpn 90566   MANAGEMENT: CMD 'status 2'
Jul 28 04:12:16 openvpn 90566   MANAGEMENT: Client connected from /var/etc/openvpn/server1.sock
Jul 28 04:11:58 openvpn 90566   rui.m/103.x.205.111:63835 SENT CONTROL [rui.m]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0,dhcp-option DOMAIN x.local,dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.2,block-outside-dns,register-dns,redirect-gateway def1,route-gateway 10.0.8.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.0.8.2 255.255.255.0' (status=1)
```

Server side config:

```
dev ovpns1
verb 3
dev-type tun
tun-ipv6
dev-node /dev/tun1
writepid /var/run/openvpn_server1.pid
#user nobody
#group nobody
script-security 3
daemon
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
proto tcp-server
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
up /usr/local/sbin/ovpn-linkup
down /usr/local/sbin/ovpn-linkdown
client-connect /usr/local/sbin/openvpn.attributes.sh
client-disconnect /usr/local/sbin/openvpn.attributes.sh
local x
engine cryptodev
tls-server
server 10.0.8.0 255.255.255.0
client-config-dir /var/etc/openvpn-csc/server1
username-as-common-name
auth-user-pass-verify "/usr/local/sbin/ovpn_auth_verify user TG9YWwRGF0YWJhcU= false server1 51194" via-env
tls-verify "/usr/local/sbin/ovpn_auth_verify tls 'xVPNca' 1"
lport 51194
management /var/etc/openvpn/server1.sock unix
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN x.local"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.2"
push "block-outside-dns"
push "register-dns"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
ca /var/etc/openvpn/server1.ca 
cert /var/etc/openvpn/server1.cert 
key /var/etc/openvpn/server1.key 
dh /etc/dh-parameters.1024
tls-auth /var/etc/openvpn/server1.tls-auth 0
comp-lzo adaptive
topology subnet
```

User Config file:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote x.dyndns.biz 51194 tcp-client
lport 0
verify-x509-name "xVPNca" name
auth-user-pass
pkcs12 pfSense-TCP-51194-x.p12
tls-auth pfSense-TCP-51194-x-tls.key 1
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo adaptive
```